# How can I access the attributes of a list that I have in my model, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two models, Model1 and Model2. The Model1 has an atribute that is a list of my model2. I need to access those attributes in my index class. I'm not sure how to do that. Here is Model1:

```
  public class Model1
{

    public Model1()
    {
        List1 = new HashSet<Model2>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Model2> List1 { get; set; }

}
```

Here is Model2:

```
    public class Model2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }   
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

}
```

here is part of my Index:

```
   $.each(data, function (i, item) {


                var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b>ABC:</b></p>' +

                    $.each(item.List1, function (f, item1) {

                        '<p>Latitude:'+ item1.Latitude+'</p>'

                    });

                   //MORE CODE

                }); 
        }); 
});
```

The code that I have above is supposed to appear on a infowindow. I want to show the latitude in a paragraph. I'm trying to do it by accessing the list. However, it gives me an 'undefined' and the paragraph doesn't even appear. 
I'm not sure how to explain it. But I hope from the code you'll understand.

Comment: Can you post your respective action code from controller?

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly inject your model information into javascript, I feel that you should step back and ask yourself if you really need to?

There may be edge cases where you have no choice but more than likely you will cause more headaches down the line.

Generating markup via HTML from your model, i would argue, is counter productive. Why not just render the markup directly in your razor:

```
@foreach (var x in Model.List1 )
{
  <p>Latitude: @x.Latitude+</p>
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need to use the data in javascript, i would consider using an ajax call to obtain the data. Since your'e using jquery :

```
$.get( "/myController/GetStuff" )
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //other code
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    console.error(error);
  })
  .always(function() {
    //hide loading animation or something
  });
```